# What’s wrong with my cutting technique?

Tags: cutting

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZhnu.jpg)

[image]

[image]

While amateur me was trying to install vinyl sheet I cut into wood, skirting board and cement wall.

How can I avoid this?  I thought maybe lightly mark the vinyl I want to cut, pull the sheet up then cut it.  Is this the way pros would do it or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are really only two fundamental solutions... either protect the surface underneath or don't cut near it. Maybe someone more skilled at vinyl flooring can chime in. That's one of those things I've rather successfully avoided needing to do over my career.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to make it an exact fit, that doesn’t work, slightly undersize and use a sealer would be my advice.

Comment: Adjust your blade so it only extends the thickness of the vinyl.