# Dealing with scratches in baseboards and concrete from flooring installation

Tags: smell, cutting

This is not the same question at all.  One asks about how to improve my cutting technique and nothing more.  This asks about how to deal with the aftermath specifically focusing on sealing in/cleaning toxins. Might have been good to link questions but they are not the same.

While installing some vinyl I accidentally cut into wood, skirting board and cement wall. Just a few questions regarding the clean up.

[image]

[image]

[image]

1. What should I fill the newly exposed wood up with? Shortly after cutting I noticed insects gather around the wood.  Does the smell of fresh wood attract insects?
2. I can smell a sligh smell from the skirting board.  Would this be freshly exposed paint or would that be wood though I cannot see any fresh wood exposed in the picture.
3. Does cutting into cement lead to the creation of any off gassing or does fine dust get created from slicing into it?

Thanks

Comment: Why have you asked the same question twice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What’s wrong with my cutting technique?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/192577/what-s-wrong-with-my-cutting-technique)

Comment: "Insects" covers several million species. Could you be much more specific?

Comment: replace the baseboard.